# What's the best way to solve this kind of javascript dead loop?

Tags: javascript, deadlock

Recently I'm maintaining a legacy project. I found one javascript dead loop problem in a page. The demo code is as follows. When the user clicks the first inputbox and type in 3 then directly click the second input box, the dead loop occurs. Now my question is what's the best way to solve or prevent this kind of problem? Great thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="a" id="a" value="" />
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var a = document.getElementById("a");
a.onblur = function(){
    if(a.value.length === 1){
        alert("aaa");
        a.focus();
        a.select();
        return false;
    }
}

var b = document.getElementById("b");
b.onblur = function(){
    if(b.value < a.value){
        alert("bbb");
        b.focus();
        b.select();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hard to tell what this code is supposed to do - looks like you are trying to have 'a' contain more than one character and 'b' to contain something that is larger than what is in 'a'. You aren't being very precise about what kind of larger either. 'a' == 'aa' and 'b' = 'ab' passes the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type" />
</head>

<body>
    <input id="a" name="a" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="b" name="b" type="text" value="" />

    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
var bInBlurA = false;
var a = document.getElementById("a");
a.onblur = function(){
    if (bInBlurB) return;
    if(a.value.length === 1){
        bInBlurA = true;
        alert("aaa2");
        a.focus();
        a.select();
    }
}

var bInBlurB = false;
var b = document.getElementById("b");
b.onblur = function(){
    if (bInBlurA) return;
    if(b.value < a.value){
        bInBlurB = true;
        alert("bbb2");
        b.focus();
        b.select();
    }
}
a.onfocus  = function()
{
    bInBlurA = false;
}
b.onfocus = function()
{
    bInBlurB = false;
}
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="a" id="a" value="" />
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var a = document.getElementById("a");
a.onblur = function() {
    a.validCheck = false;
    if(a.value.length === 1){
        alert("aaa");
        a.focus();
        a.select();
        return false;
    }
    a.validCheck = true;
}

var b = document.getElementById("b");
b.onblur = function() {
    if (!a.validCheck) return true;
    if(b.value < a.value){
        alert("bbb");
        b.focus();
        b.select();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Plus I didn't have any loop problems in Firefox although it doesn't behave as intended. I'm assuming this is IE only.

Answer (score 0):

What do u mean by this line:

```
if(b.value < a.value){
```

If you are comparing length, do this:

```
if(b.value.length < a.value.length){
```

Or if you want to check if they are equal or not then:

```
if(b.value == a.value){
```

Or

```
if(b.value != a.value){
```

Comment: Hi Sarfraz, **if(b.value < a.value){** is just a demo condition. I just want to say that there is some condition there.

Comment: what exactly do u want to do?